# How to send a transaction for Cardano native assets via CLI?

Tags: cardano-cli, native-assets, utxo

For example to list UTXO is something like this

```
cardano-cli query utxo —mainnet —address addrX
```

which returns as an example

```
                               TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
txHashA     0        1500000 lovelace
txHashB     1        1500000 lovelace
```

but for native assets it returns the UTXO as the following (NFT example)

```
                           TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
txHashC     0        1500000 lovelace + 1 someHash???.SomeNft1
txHashD     1        1500000 lovelace + 1 someHash???.SomeNft2
```

My main goal is to understand how to send one to many native assets in a single transaction

Comment: I'm having trouble signing this transaction. I get: Invalid argument `payment.vkey'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, according to the [docs.cardano.org](https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/getting-started):

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
         --mary-era \
             --fee 178393 \
             --tx-in fd0790f3984348f65ee22f35480b873b4eb9862065514f3e3a9c0f04d0a6ad63#0 \
             --tx-out addr_test1vp8s8zu6mr73nvlsjf935k0a38n8xvp3fptkyz2vl8pserqkcx5yz+10000000+"1 328a60495759e0d8e244eca5b85b2467d142c8a755d6cd0592dff47b.melcoin" \
             --tx-out addr_test1vqvlku0ytscqg32rpv660uu4sgxlje25s5xrpz7zjqsva3c8pfckz+989643522+"999999999 328a60495759e0d8e244eca5b85b2467d142c8a755d6cd0592dff47b.melcoin" \
             --out-file rec_matx.raw
```